# How to create a postgres column with a default timestamp value of epoch?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create a timestamp column with a default value of epoch. How can I do it? This, and all the variations I've tried don't work:

```
...
last_viewed_at     TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT TIMESTAMP "epoch",
...
```

Comment: `DEFAULT current_timestamp`

Comment: Epoch means 1970-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: then write that explicitely: `timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's all about double quotes vs single quotes. Double quotes are for identifiers so you want:

```
...
last_viewed_at     TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT TIMESTAMP 'epoch',
...
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/682d0/2)